# Loading json from local directory

Tags: jquery, json

I have a button click that tries to load a json file. It never reaches the success function.
I presume I can load a json file locally and not have to have it on a server?
Why would this not work.

```
$(function(){
    $('.demo').click(function(){

            $.ajax({
            url: 'data/demo.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log("data = ", data)
                        }
        });

    });
});
```

here is my folder structure tree.

- index.html
- data (folder)

  - demo.json js
- page.js

**JSON**

```
{"markers": [
        {
            "point":new GLatLng(40.266044,-74.718479),
            "homeTeam":"Lawrence Library",
            "awayTeam":"LUGip",
            "markerImage":"images/red.png",
            "information": "Linux users group meets second Wednesday of each month.",
            "fixture":"Wednesday 7pm",
            "capacity":"",
            "previousScore":""
        },
        {
            "point":new GLatLng(40.211600,-74.695702),
            "homeTeam":"Hamilton Library",
            "awayTeam":"LUGip HW SIG",
            "markerImage":"images/white.png",
            "information": "Linux users can meet the first Tuesday of the month to work out harward and configuration issues.",
            "fixture":"Tuesday 7pm",
            "capacity":"",
            "tv":""
        },
        {
            "point":new GLatLng(40.294535,-74.682012),
            "homeTeam":"Applebees",
            "awayTeam":"After LUPip Mtg Spot",
            "markerImage":"images/newcastle.png",
            "information": "Some of us go there after the main LUGip meeting, drink brews, and talk.",
            "fixture":"Wednesday whenever",
            "capacity":"2 to 4 pints",
            "tv":""
        },
] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have a similar script, and it accesses a local file and works fine.  The problem I see here is your JSON is invalid.  Maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Ok thats good to know as everyone else here says you can't. Can you give me a valid json files so I can test. I nabbed this one from online as a tester so I presumed it was valid.

Comment: Run it through http://jsonlint.com/.  The errors are the"point": newGLatLng(40.294535, -74.68201) lines.  They need to be surrounded by double quotes.  It would work if there was a function changing those values, but if you are using it as a static file, it will never work.

Comment: Thank you Dean that worked. I'm glad you cleared up that you could in fact load json locally.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use AJAX to access local files even if the page is served locally from a file

Comment: Ok can you give me an example of how I would load this file?

Comment: @JuanMendes Are there other access methods to local files than AJAX?